# Suggestions for a pluggable task framework in Django

Tags: python, django, plugins

I am developing a website which is aimed at being a GUI for several image processing algorithms (referred to as 'tasks').

At the moment, only one of these algorithms is finished, but there are more to come (which will have a similar, but not quite the same, workflow)

Basically, the algorithm works as follows (not that it matters a lot, but just for the sake of clarity):
1) Enter some parameters and an input image
2) run algorithm part one
--algorithm runs--
3) review an interim result
4) edit the parameters if needed, and go to 2.
5) run algorithm part two
--algorithm runs--
6) review the result
7) adjust some of the interim results if needed, and go to 5
8) all done

I expect some of the additional tasks to have a rather similar work flow, though it is perfectly possible that they won't.

So, the easy way to implement this would be to create a separate django application for each algorithm.

However, I'd like to be able to browse through a sorted list (by time of completion) of completed tasks, and for each of these task display a summary (name, description, start time, thumbnail).

Is there anyone that can provide me with some suggestions on how I can implement this? I'd like to keep it as simple as possible, so additional task can be 'plugged' in as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an app with a very abstract definition of a `Task` model. The `Task` model might contain properties for:

- the input arguments,
- the function to run,
- the time that the task was submitted,
- the time that the task has been actually running, and
- the result (which would be something like a singleton `Task.NotFinished` until finished).

You could consider using `twisted` to run the tasks because:

- `twisted` has a well designed and tested implementation of asynchronous tasks; and
- you could run the tasks on other processors or machines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Right now I am using something like you suggest, implemented with celery (which uses RabbitMQ as load handler). 
And although it works fine, the problem with that however is that there's no way to communicate with the task once it has started, which is also a requirement.

I'll definitely look into twisted.


Though I think I might turn down my requirements for this, until I have more information about the additional algorithms.